# Cloud Run - Attach compressed file to response

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer, google-cloud-run

I'm running a test environment of Google's Cloud Run using the **functions-framework** package on Node. I'm currently trying to attach a zip file to my response using .download but I don't believe the file exists in the test cloud instance while it does on my files? Sorry, I'm really not too familiar with what is happening.

tldr: I'm trying to prompt for a download of the zip containing all of the images on the site, but I'm having trouble attaching the zip to the response

index.js

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const archiver = require("archiver");
const fs = require("fs");

exports.screenshot = async (req, res) => {
  var output = fs.createWriteStream("./example.zip");
  var archive = archiver("zip");

  archive.on("error", function (err) {
    throw err;
  });

  archive.pipe(output);

  let browserPromise = puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox"],
  });

  const url = req.query.url || "http://example.org";

  const browser = await browserPromise;
  const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  await page.setViewport({ width: 3840, height: 2160 });
  await page.goto(url);

  const images = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("img"), (e) => [
      e.x,
      e.y,
      e.width,
      e.height,
    ])
  );
 count = 0;
  await asyncForEach(images, async (image) => {
    count++;
    await page.evaluate(
      (y) => document.scrollingElement.scrollTo(0, y),
      image[1]
    );
    await page.screenshot({
      path: `image.png`,
      clip: {
        x: image[0],
        y: image[1],
        width: image[2],
        height: image[3],
      },
    });
    if (count < 10) {
      archive.file("./image.png", { name: `0${count}.png` });
    } else {
      archive.file("./image.png", { name: `${count}.png` });
    }
  });

  archive.finalize();
  //res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
  // res.set("Content-Type", "application/zip");
  // res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "example.zip");
  // res.download("/example.zip", "result.zip");
  // res.send("example.zip");

  context.close();
};

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "functions-framework --target=screenshot"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.7.1",
    "archiver": "^5.1.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "puppeteer": "^5.5.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for Cloud Run there is no built-in storage mechanism, Files can only be temporarily stored for processing in a container instance, but this means that you cannot "deploy" a file alongside your app to be processed.

For persistent storage you would have to integrate your app with [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).